# Android: Layout looks different on same screen resolution devices

Tags: android, layout

I'm new in Android programming. I have a quiz game. In the main activity you can tap one of the 4 answers to see the result if correct or not. My problem is the following: I've tested this select options on S4 mini which shows the select options in good size, but on Sony Xperia M2 is look twice bigger! Both devices has the same screen resolution (540 x 960 pixels).

This is my code (M280) in the main activity:

```
final Point dim = Utils.getScreenDimensions(MainActivity.this);
int M280 = 280;
            if (SplashActivity.bSmallScreen) {
                M280 = 60;
            }

            if (dim.y == 240 && dim.x == 320) {
                M280 = 60;
            }

            if (dim.y == 320 && dim.x == 480) {
                M280 = 80;
            }

            if (dim.y == 480 && dim.x == 800) {
                M280 = 140;
            }

            if (dim.y == 480 && dim.x == 854) {
                M280 = 140;
            }

            if (dim.y == 540 && dim.x == 960) {
                M280 = 160;
            }

            if (dim.y == 720 && dim.x == 1280) {
                M280 = 200;
            }

            if (dim.y == 768 && dim.x == 1280) {
                M280 = 200;
            }

            if (dim.y == 800 && dim.x == 1280) {
                M280 = 220;
            }

            if (dim.y == 1080 && dim.x == 1920) {
                M280 = 280;
            }

            if (dim.y == 1440 && dim.x == 2560) {
                M280 = 300;
            }

            if (Utils.isTablet(mContext)) {
                M280 = 300;
            }
            if (i==0) {
                final LinearLayout LL2Row = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);

                final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        M280);
                LL2Row.setLayoutParams(lp);
                LL2Row.setTag("LL21");
                LL2Row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                LL2Row.setWeightSum(2);

                LLQuestionAnswers.addView(LL2Row);
            }

            //TODO new, 2-nal hozzaadunk egy ll-t ami 2 reszbol all
            if (i==2) {
                final LinearLayout LL2Row = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);

                final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        M280);

                LL2Row.setLayoutParams(lp);
                LL2Row.setTag("LL22");
                LL2Row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                LL2Row.setWeightSum(2);

                LLQuestionAnswers.addView(LL2Row);
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to Android. Learn about screen densities - devices might have the same resolution, but different physical sizes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Both devices has almost the same densities.

Comment: Xperia has: 229 ppi pixel density
S4 mini has: 256 ppi pixel density

Comment: How do you get `dim.x` and `dim.y`? You're possibly using an unreliable method (I experimented that some methods of displayMetrics for getting the size **LIE**).

Comment: @FarkasAntal Go through this [http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and this [http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) links.You get idea an about multi-screens designs and screen densities.

Comment: Hi @DerGolem, I get the dim.x and dim.y by this code:
final Point dim = Utils.getScreenDimensions(MainActivity.this);

Comment: I **guess** that the custom `getScreenDimensions() `method in the custom `Utils` class: `Utils.getScreenDimensions()` is using the [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) object...

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers. I've visited those links, but still I have no idea how to fix it. Do I need to remove these codes from the main activity and use the layout option for different densities?

Comment: Your code is using some wrong logic: `if (dim.y == 540 && dim.x == 960) {
                M280 = 160;
            }` what is **160**? dpi? so it's wrong in both cases, since you should return the normalized density of **240 dpi** for both devices. `Xperia has: 229 ppi pixel density S4 mini has: 256 ppi pixel density` this resolves for both to the normalized **hdpi (240 dpi)** density.

Comment: I'm sorry, probably I need to share more code:   

`if (i==0) {
     final LinearLayout LL2Row = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
     
     final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                M280);
     LL2Row.setLayoutParams(lp);
     LL2Row.setTag("LL21");
     LL2Row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
     LL2Row.setWeightSum(2);
     
     LLQuestionAnswers.addView(LL2Row);
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With current device sizes, aspect ratios and density fragmentation, 
always prioritize using ratios when designing interface whether its on Android or iOS.

something like this:
[image: UI designed with relative ratios]

for Android:

- Try to use LinearLayouts as much as you can, keeping a weight-sum on parent view and distributing them in child views this way views will stretch to the same ratio irrespective of displaytype, [tutorial](http://www.chess-ix.com/blog/the-use-of-layout_weight-with-android-layouts)
- Try to use wrap_content and match_parent/fill_parent as much as you can, avoid using hard-coded "dp" values whenever possible.
- If you need to use other viewgroups like RelativeLayouts

  1)Keep a Parent RelativeLayout
  2)Which has child LinearLayouts 
  3)Keep your subviews in that LinearLayout.

Gets a little more extra time to design but saves a lot of headache when targeting many devices

something like this:

[image: layout mock]

for iOS:

use Auto Layout which is similar to weights and weight-sum, [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)